# HTML Purifier remove TinyMCE HTML 5 video tag

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce, html5-video, htmlpurifier

I am using TinyMCE and HTMLPurifier in a Symfony2 application.

I need to embed some internals videos of the website with TinyMCE. The problem is that HTML Purifier **don't accept HTML5 video tag** and remove them.

Is there someone to let me know how can I configure TinyMCE/HTMLPurifier to permit videos embedding?

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?2,7417,7417   no idea if that's since changed, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle, I sligthly addapt the transformer to accept the video tag.

Find full HTML5 config here : https://github.com/kennberg/php-htmlpurfier-html5

```
<?php

namespace Exercise\HTMLPurifierBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class HTMLPurifierTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $purifier;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param \HTMLPurifier $purifier
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
          //Find full HTML5 config : https://github.com/kennberg/php-htmlpurfier-html5
          $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
          $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');

          // Set some HTML5 properties
          $config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'html5-definitions'); // unqiue id
          $config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
          if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
            // http://developers.whatwg.org/the-video-element.html#the-video-element
            $def->addElement('video', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', array(
              'src' => 'URI',
              'type' => 'Text',
              'width' => 'Length',
              'height' => 'Length',
              'poster' => 'URI',
              'preload' => 'Enum#auto,metadata,none',
              'controls' => 'Bool',
            ));
            $def->addElement('source', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', array(
              'src' => 'URI',
              'type' => 'Text',
            ));
          }
          $this->purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
    }

    /**
     * @see Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface::transform()
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @see Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface::reverseTransform()
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        return $this->purifier->purify($value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2018-04-16**

Adapt code to avoid "src" removing with last [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) version.

More options : https://github.com/kennberg/php-htmlpurfier-html5/blob/master/htmlpurifier_html5.php

Comment: i use ezyang/HTMLPurifier in Yii2 , but i have this error Element 'video' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums) , with this code: $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'video[src|type|width|height|poster|preload|controls]');